# Taylor expansion for random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, taylor-expansion

Suppose a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges in probability to a random variable $X$. We know that $X \geq 1$. Does the following Taylor expansion hold?
$$\frac{1}{X_n} - \frac{1}{X} = -\frac{1}{X}(X_n - X) + O_p(|X_n - X|^2)$$

If $X$ is a nonrandom number, then this is just the delta method. But now $X$ is a random variable, the delta method argument no longer applies.

Comment: Could you make the equation more rigorous? I cannot fully understand the statement you want to prove.

Comment: @VezenBU Thanks for the reply! For numbers b>a>0, the Taylor expansion of the reciprocal function gives that 1/b - 1/a = -1/a * (b-a) + O((b-a)^2). I want to know whether this holds if we replace a, b by X, Xn